# How to remove non-numeric characters from string input in C#?

Tags: c#, string, textbox

I am making a calculator as a Windows Form application. In order to evade FormatException, I need to remove the symbols like space, special symbols, or letters from the TextBox.

```
if (textBox1.Text[textBox1.Text.Length - 1] == '.')
    textBox1.Text += '0';
for (int i = 0; i < textBox1.Text.Length; i++)
    if (!((textBox1.Text[i] == 0) || (textBox1.Text[i] == 1) ||
        (textBox1.Text[i] == 2) || (textBox1.Text[i] == 3) ||
        (textBox1.Text[i] == 4) || (textBox1.Text[i] == 5) ||
        (textBox1.Text[i] == 6) || (textBox1.Text[i] == 7) ||
        (textBox1.Text[i] == 8) || (textBox1.Text[i] == 9) ||
        (textBox1.Text[i] == '.')))
            textBox1.Text[i] = '';
    
number = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text);
calculatorBLL.OperatorClicked(Operator, number);
```

My first idea was to use the `Remove(i)` function, but it removes all the characters starting from the invalid one, so I decided to go with `textBox1.Text[i] = ''` instead. However, assigning empty character literal is not allowed.
Besides, neither of methods seems to work: `'string.this[int]' cannot be assigned to -- it is read only`

Comment: Ditch all of that. Use the [appropriate numerical input control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/controls/set-and-return-numeric-values-with-wf-numericupdown-control?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8) instead of a text box. Then you don't have that problem in the first place.

Comment: @Fildor So basically, I have to only rely on buttons and make text readonly, is that right?

Comment: See the link I edited into my comment above.

Comment: maybe use Regex to validate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of removing the non-numeric characters from the TextBox value, I believe it's simpler and easier to just create a new string based on the numeric characters. Also, instead of checking for each of the radix-10 digits, it's better to use the [Char.IsDigit Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.char.isdigit?view=net-8.0) method instead. Your code then becomes

```cs
if (textBox1.Text[textBox1.Text.Length - 1] == '.')
    textBox1.Text += '0';
string numstr = "";
for (int i = 0; i < textBox1.Text.Length; i++)
    if (Char.IsDigit(textBox1.Text[i]) || textBox1.Text[i] == '.')
        numstr += textBox1.Text[i];
    
number = Convert.ToInt32(numstr);
calculatorBLL.OperatorClicked(Operator, number);
```

There are various other improvements you can also make. For example, slightly better efficiency, and fewer reallocations, could be obtained by using a [StringBuilder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.stringbuilder?view=net-8.0) instead of a string, but for the number of characters you'll use it for, this is minimal. Also, you should probably check for things like the resulting string not being empty, not more than one period being used, the string not representing too large an integer, etc.

Nonetheless, such as indicated in [Fildor's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77936451/how-to-remove-non-numeric-characters-from-string-input-in-c/77936582#comment137398116_77936582), there are generally simpler ways to deal with this issue, such as to "... use the appropriate UI component to begin with or use winforms user input validation". Thus, unless this is for something like an assignment or for other learning purposes, an alternate method like that should be used instead.

Comment: @Fildor Thank you for your feedback. I agree that what the OP is doing is not the generally the recommended way. However, I was addressing their specific question about how to specifically improve what they were doing, for example if it's part of an assignment or for their general learning purposes. Nonetheless, I've added about this to my answer, including what you wrote in your comment.

Comment: Sorry, removed that comment. But I think your remark is sufficient to point out, we should generally use the right tools for the job.

Comment: ^^ Like if it were a "yes/no", probably everybody would straight away go for a check box -ish control. No questions asked. I'll never get why numeric input should be different.

Comment: This is quite literally a small colege assignment, so I will only add checks for one decimal point and blank input